# Iterate through Dictionary to determine player positions

Tags: ios, dictionary

I am working on a card playing game for four players. I save these player objects in a Dictionary with a simple ID; 1, 2, 3, 4. Then I determine the starting player randomly.

In the game view I have the four players assigned to different areas of the screen. The player of the current device is always the player at the bottom of the screen, the next is left on the screen, third is at the top and the fourth is at the right.

Let's assume that the player of the device is player with ID 3 in the players Dictionary. The placing of the players on screen will be; 1 (up), 2 (right), 3 (bottom) and 4 (left). They're placed clockwise according their position in the Dictionary.

I have this code to determine the positions. To be clear; bottom = 1, left = 2, top = 3 and right = 4.

```
func determinePlayerPositions() {
    var playerPositionsCount = 0

    for i in 1...gamePlayers.count {
        let player = gamePlayers[i]

        if player?.playerID == playerOfThisDeviceId {
            playerOfThisDevice = i
            playerPositions[1] = playerOfThisDevice
            playerPositionsCount += 1

            if playerOfThisDevice == gamePlayers.count && playerPositionsCount != gamePlayers.count {

                for i in 1...gamePlayers.count-1 {

                    playerPositions[i] = i
                    playerPositionsCount += 1
                }
            }

            if playerOfThisDevice < gamePlayers.count && playerPositionsCount != gamePlayers.count {

                for i in playerOfThisDevice+1...gamePlayers.count {
                    playerPositions[i] = i
                    playerPositionsCount += 1
                }

                if playerPositionsCount != gamePlayers.count {
                    for i in 1...playerPositionsCount {
                        playerPositions[i] = i
                    }

                    playerPositionsCount = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setLabelTexts()

}
```

The bottom player differs on the four different devices playing the game obviously.

So it works, but my question is; is there a more efficient way of determining the positions. This seems a lot of code for just a simple task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the players array by the current player so to make the current player the first element.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [3, 4, 1, 2] // where current player has ID 3
```

When arranged like this, the index of a player maps to a position index.

```
enum Position: Int {
    case bottom = 1
    case left = 2
    case top = 3
    case right = 4
}

struct Player {
    let id: Int
}

struct Game {
    let current: Player
    let players: [Player]

    func position(of player: Player) -> Position? {

        let slices = players.split(whereSeparator: { $0.id == current.id })
        let ordered = [current] + slices.last! + slices.first!
        let index = ordered.index(where: { $0.id == player.id })

        return index.flatMap { Position(rawValue: $0 + 1) }
    }
}

let game = Game(
    current: Player(id: 3),
    players: [
        Player(id: 1),
        Player(id: 2),
        Player(id: 3),
        Player(id: 4)
    ]
)

print(game.position(of: Player(id: 3)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!